# Manipulate form fields from cloned table row jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp

I have a form that I decided to split into tabs(based on bootstrap) to make it easier to manage due to the length of the form(imagine each tab as a step, but its not a wizard per se, as I am not really interested in building it wizard like), each tab, contains specific information for the form, in 2 of 6 tabs, I have a table (different table in each tab), where with a button I'm cloning the first "child" of the "tbody" tag with a jquery function, and deleting (if required, any element "but" the first child.

```
<script>
// function to clone last child in the nearest table.
$('.cloneLastChild').click(function() {
    var parentControl = $('#' + $(this).closest('.table').attr('id'));
    var counter = parentControl.children('tbody').size();
    //console.log(counter);
    parentControl.children('tbody:first').clone().appendTo(parentControl);
return false;
});
// function to delete the last child of a table, but always leave 1.
$('.removeLastChild').click(function() {
var parentControl = $('#' + $(this).closest('.table').attr('id'));
parentControl.children('tbody').not(':first').last().remove();
return false;
});
```

as I'm using a table, I'm adding it specifically to the nearest table to the "this" element.

I'm using CakePHP to build this project, due to customer's requirements, The naming of the elements, is where the problem comes forth.

here is the code for the specific tab thats giving me "naming manipulation" problems.

```
<!-- paso 3.2 -->
<div class="tab-pane fade in" id="paso3-2">
    <!-- fieldset -->
    <fieldset>
        <legend class="h5">3.2. Actividades Generales a Realizar</legend>
        <h4 class="h4">Duración del Proyecto:</h4>
        <!-- form-group -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="fecha_inicio" class="col-md-2 control-label">Fecha de Inicio:</label> 
            <!-- col-md-10 -->
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="data[Proyecto][fecha_inicio]" id="fecha_inicio" placeholder="Fecha de Inicio">
            </div><!-- ./cold-md-10 -->
            <label for="fecha_final" class="col-md-2 control-label datepicker">Fecha de Culminaci&oacute;n:</label> 
            <!-- col-md-10 -->
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="data[Proyecto][fecha_final]" id="fecha_final" placeholder="Fecha de Culminaci&oacute;n">
            </div><!-- ./cold-md-10 -->
        </div><!-- ./form-group -->
        <h4>Se&ntilde;ale las actividades generales a realizar especificando los meses de ejecuci&oacute;n</h4>
        <br><br>
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="tablaAtividadesLista">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="col-md-1" rowspan="2">N#</th>
                    <th class="col-md-10" rowspan="2">Actividades a desarrollar</th>
                    <th colspan="12"><h4>Meses de Inicio y Culminaci&oacute;n de Actividades</h4></th>
                    <th rowspan="2"><a href="javascript:;" class="cloneLastChild"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span></a><a href="javascript:;" class="removeLastChild"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></span></a></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Ene</th>
                    <th>Feb</th>
                    <th>Mar</th>
                    <th>Abr</th>
                    <th>May</th>
                    <th>Jun</th>
                    <th>Jul</th>
                    <th>Ago</th>
                    <th>Sep</th>
                    <th>Oct</th>
                    <th>Nov</th>
                    <th>Dic</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
```

Below this is the first children

```
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <!-- form-group -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="ActividadProyectosOrden" class="col-md-1 control-label"></label> 
                            <!-- col-md-10 -->
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <?php echo $this->form->input('ActividadProyectos.0.orden', array('div' => false, 'label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '#')); ?>
                            </div><!-- ./cold-md-10 -->
                        </div><!-- ./form-group -->
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <!-- form-group -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="ActividadProyectosDescripcion" class="col-md-1 control-label"></label> 
                            <!-- col-md-10 -->
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                <?php echo $this->form->input('ActividadProyectos.0.descripcion', array('div' => false, 'label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '#')); ?>
                            </div><!-- ./cold-md-10 -->
                        </div><!-- ./form-group -->
                    </td>
                    <?php
                        for($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++){ ?>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $this->form->input('ActividadProyectos.0.duracion.'.$i.'', array('div' => false, 'label' => false, 'type' => 'checkbox', 'id' => 'ActividadProyectos.duracion.'.$i.'')); ?>
                    </td>
                    <?php } ?>
                </tr>
```

here above ends the first children and continues the rest of the tab code.

```
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <!-- form-group -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="telf2" class="col-md-1 control-label">Direcci&oacute;n del evento:</label> 
            <!-- col-md-10 -->
            <div class="col-md-11">
                <textarea rows="3" class="form-control textarea" id="address" placeholder="Direcci&oacute;n del evento"></textarea>
            </div><!-- ./cold-md-10 -->
        </div><!-- ./form-group -->
        <!-- form-group -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="pais" class="col-md-1 control-label">Pa&iacute;s:</label> 
            <!-- col-md-10 -->
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                </select>
            </div><!-- ./cold-md-10 -->
            <label for="estado" class="col-md-1 control-label">Estado:</label> 
            <!-- col-md-10 -->
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                </select>
            </div><!-- ./cold-md-10 -->
            <label for="ciudad" class="col-md-1 control-label">Ciudad:</label> 
            <!-- col-md-10 -->
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                </select>
            </div><!-- ./cold-md-10 -->
        </div><!-- ./form-group -->
    </fieldset><!-- ./fieldset -->
</div><!-- ./paso 3.2 -->
```

When im cloning the last child, the problem Im facing is, I have several form elements, that I need to change the name to "Modelname.NEXTROW.fieldname", the first child, is named "Modelname.0.fieldname", how can i make it, so each cloned element, changes the name from [Modelname].0.[fieldname] to [Modelname].1/2/3/4/5/6 and so forth.[fieldname] as each row gets cloned,

I have a counter variable set and works as intended, if I add 2 new childs, it prints whichever position I'm in to the console when uncommented, if i delete 2, but add 1, it prints the current count, so I'm covered there.

the fields I'm having problems with are those of the first children, as you can see, they are named:

ActividadProyectos.0.fieldname

If you noted in the code, I have a for loop, in a table, that repeats a checkbox, that represent "months", that i need those values in a single array, of 0 and 1, separated by comma, where 1 means month active, and 0 month inactive, for other modules to access and process the data

what I need is, then in short, each cloned child, should change `ActividadProyectos.0.fieldname`, to `ActividadProyectos.counter.fieldname`.

any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I solved this problem instead of manipulating the dom element, with an injection, ussing append, instead of clone, and using an acumulator variable. thanks anyway for the help on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just get the amount of rows generated by CakePHP in the HTML output:

http://api.jquery.com/length/

```
var rowCount = $("#table tr").length
// in your loop:
rowCount++;
```

And start from there to iterate from this value when adding copies to the table.

Comment: your reply  does not really apply to my problem, I already have a counter added in my $('.cloneLastChild').click(function(), what i need is a way to manipulate the name attribute of the 27 fields that are cloned alonside the table row, and change the 0 with the counter variable, so each new row field is named ActividadProyectos.COUNTER.field

Comment: This by no means solves the problem, thanks anyway for the help, indeed im using now a counter, tho not for what you seem to think i needed it.